# Recognize google places in voice data of SpeechRecognition API python

Tags: api, speech

How can I get google to recognize the places through there google places API, I can  get API key for Google Places API but I can't ffind documentation for how to get recognize the places name in below code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from threading import Thread
r = sr.Recognizer()  
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    while True:
        print("Please wait. Calibrating microphone...")
        # listen for 5 seconds and create the ambient noise energy leve
        print("Say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        # recognize speech using Sphinx
        try:
           print("Google thinks you said '" + r.recognize_google(audio) + 
"'")
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Google could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Google error; {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: I don't see anything Google Places related in your code... what have you tried to access their API and what problems have you been facing?